# Where to download Netflix Astyanax dependencies?

Tags: gradle, astyanax

I want to include Astyanax into my project. I checkout the code from github and compiled it with "gradlew build". I am not familiar with gradle.

I include the Astyanx jar files manually into my project. When I run it, it complains about missing Jar.

I wonder, where I can download all the dependencies bundle for Astyanax?

Comment: why don't you use Maven or Gradle to retrieve Astyanax and all it's dependencies from Maven Central?

Comment: because I am not good at Maven / Gradle. Instead of spending time to learn Maven / Gradle, I wish to start using Astyanax immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Java library projects often don't provide a single download location for their dependencies. Instead, you would typically use a build tool that supports Maven repositories (e.g. Maven or Gradle) for your own project, which would then automatically download required dependencies behind the scenes.

If you do want to get hold of all dependencies for the Astyanax project, try to add the following to its `build.gradle`:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "libs"
}
```

Running `gradlew copyLibs` should then copy all (compile and runtime) dependencies into the `libs` directory.

Comment: $ gradlew copyLibs
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'astyanax'.
> Could not find property 'runtime' on configuration container.

Comment: Try something like: `allprojects { plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) { task copyLibs(type: Copy) { from configurations.runtime; into "$rootProject.projectDir/libs" } } }`